# Executorフレームワークについて

Tags: java

以下のようなメソッドを持った共有オブジェクトクラスを、Threadクラスを継承する方法やRunnableインターフェイスを実装する方法ではなく、Executorフレームワークを使って利用し、set()メソッドとreset()メソッドが交互に呼び出され出力するように実装してみたいです。

しかし、コードの書き方が悪いのか(おそらく)デッドロック状態になってしまい、うまくいきません。newFixedThreadPool(2)メソッドで、2つのメソッドを2つのスレッドがそれぞれ担当し、実行順序まで制御することは可能でしょうか？

もしクラス設計に問題がある場合は、クラスの作り方を変えても構いません。

```
class Share {
     private int a = 0;
     private String b;

     public synchronized void set() {
          while(a != 0) {
              try {
                   wait();
              } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              notify();
              a++;
              b = "data";
              System.out.println("set() a : " + a + " b: " + b);
          }
     }
     public synchronized void reset() {
          while(b == null) {
              try {
                   wait();
              } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              notify();
              a--;
              b = null;
              System.out.println("reset() a : " + a +" b: " + b);
          }
     }
}
```

※以下、Threadクラスを継承したサブクラスを2つ作り、run()メソッドの中でそれぞれset()、reset()メソッドを呼び出すよう定義し、mainでstart()を呼び出すとうまくいきますが、Executorで単純な動作から学びたく質問させて頂きました。

何故かクラスとフィールド、クラスブロックが飛び出していてすいません。

※追記

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     ExecutorService service = null;

     try {
         service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

         Runnable task1 = () -> {
              for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                   new Share().set();
              }
         };

         Runnable task2 = () -> {
              for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                   new Share().reset();
              }
         };
         
         service.execute(task1);
         service.execute(task2);

         service.shutdown();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

行いたいことは大体こんな感じでしょうか。

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Share share = new Share();

        final Runnable setter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                share.set();
            }
        };
        final Runnable resetter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                share.reset();
            }
        };

        final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        // 注: 厳密には、setメソッドの方がresetより先に呼ばれる保証は無い(はず)
        es.execute(setter);
        es.execute(resetter);

    }
}

class Share {
    private int a = 0;
    private String b;

    public synchronized void set() {
        System.out.println("called set");
        do {
            a++;
            b = "data";
            System.out.println("set() a : " + a + " b: " + b);

            notify();

            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("setter waked");
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (a == 0);
    }

    public synchronized void reset() {
        System.out.println("called reset");
        do {
            a--;
            b = null;
            System.out.println("reset() a : " + a + " b: " + b);

            notify();

            try {
                wait();
                System.out.println("resetter waked");
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (b != null);
    }
}
```

---

> (おそらく)デッドロック状態になってしまい、うまくいきません。

書かれているコードについては、(どのように実行しているかにもよりますが、おそらく、)デッドロックになっているわけではなく、 `set` メソッドは `a==0` なので `while` ループに入らず即座にリターンし、また、 `reset` メソッドは最初の `wait()` で無限に待ち状態に入っています。

---

追記されている `main` メソッドの中では呼び出しごとに `new Share()` が行われているので、`set`と`reset`で何の協調動作もなく単に並行に動作している状態です。
どういう動作になることを想定されていますか？

Comment: yukihaneさん、ありがとうございます！ひとまず両方のメソッドが呼び出されるようになりました。実は両方のメソッドを5回ずつループさせたいのですが、追記のようなコードを書いてみたところやはり途中で処理が止まってしまいます。何が問題でしょうか？

Comment: 現時点で動作させようとしているコードを書いてみてもらえるでしょうか(`Share`クラスはどのように変更されたでしょうか、あるいは変更せずに質問文のままでしょうか)。

Comment: yukihaneさん、ありがとうございます！クラスはyukihaneさんのクラスをそのまま使わせていただいて、mainでの実行処理は本文に「※追記」として加えさせてもらいました！